# Get culture-specific date with 2 digit year in C#

Tags: c#, .net, localization, globalization, datetime-format

I'm updating some code that formats a date to a string using "MM/dd/yy". I need it to be culture aware, but want to keep the two digit year in order to keep the date short. Below is what I came up with, but is there a better way?

```
string dateFormat = culture_Info.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern.Replace("yyyy", "yy");
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know of any way, no (and I've looked at the formatting reasonably extensively). What you've got obviously still leaves a bit of a nasty taste in the mouth, but I think it's the best you can do.

Answer (score 0):

As Jon says, I don't believe there is any way to do what you want by default. But the real question is: do you really need to do it? You're only gaining a couple of bytes by doing so, after all. Is it worth the "nasty taste in the mouth?"

Comment: That's a valid point. I'm just trying to match the format already being used. It's part of a short description string so I think the goal was to keep it as short as possible.