# Culture sensitive DateTime.ToString with dd and MM

Tags: c#, wpf, datetime-format

I am wanting to display a list of dates in a WPF app in short date format with padded days and months.

i.e. in Australia/UK, this should appear as dd/MM/yyyy. In the US it would appears as MM/dd/yyyy

Is there a culture sensitive straightforward/simple method or pattern I can use to do this?

```
 DateTime.ToShortDateString()
```

does not pad the day and month.

Comment: what do you mean by padding?

Comment: the format dd will pad the date with a "0" if it is only a single digit. i.e. the first of November in Australia will be 01/11 instead of 1/11

Comment: It appears Jon Skeet addresses a similar issue here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9006806/get-culture-specific-date-with-2-digit-year-in-c-sharp?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CultureInfo is built into .NET framework so that you do not have to concern yourself with the details of formatting dates for each culture. So you should just do `DateTime.ToShortDateString()` and be done with it.

That being said, we can modify the CultureInfo ShortDatePattern to get what you want.

```
static void Main()
{
    DateTime date = new DateTime(2014, 1, 2);

    // Change our CuurentCulture to: US
    CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-us");

    // Standard format for US: 1/2/2014
    Console.WriteLine(date.ToString("d"));        

    // Force leading zero on month and day for US format: 01/02/2014
    Console.WriteLine(GetShortDateString(date));



    // Change our CuurentCulture to: AU
    CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-au");

    // Standard format for AU: 2/01/2014
    Console.WriteLine(date.ToString("d"));

    // Force leading zero on day for AU format: 02/01/2014
    Console.WriteLine(GetShortDateString(date));        
}

static string GetShortDateString(DateTime date)
{
    string format = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern;

    if (!format.Contains("dd"))
        format = format.Replace("d", "dd");

    if (!format.Contains("MM"))
        format = format.Replace("M", "MM");

    return date.ToString(format);
}
```

Comment: As always I just came up with a similar answer. Was going to go with:
dt.ToString(d.ShortDatePattern.Replace("dd", "d").Replace("d", "dd").Replace("MM", "M").Replace("M", "MM")))
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [DateTimeFormatInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) class which formats `DateTime` values depending on culture.

Comment: I can't see anything methods or properties on this class that will help me format the string as I've specified. Can you please provide more information?